# jQuery Tabs: Turn off Animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-tabs

I have a page with jquery tabs where I've tied a function to the show event.  Apparently, by doing just this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#myTabs').tabs({ show: function() {} });    
});
```

it turns an animation effect on when switching between the tabs (http://jsfiddle.net/22unj/)

How do I go about turning that off without removing my show handler?

Comment: Show is not a tab event, it's an option.

Comment: do you just want an event hooked to the creation?

Comment: I need my event to trigger anytime the tabs are switched, as well as for the initially displayed tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. [Option show](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-show) is used to determine how to animate tabs. Maybe what you want is [Method activate](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate) ?

```
$(function() {
    $('#myTabs').tabs({ activate: function() {doSomething();}, create: function() {doSomething();} });    

    function doSomething() {
        console.log('hello world!');
    }

});
```

Comment: Looks like that's what I'm needing, however it doesn't look like it fires for the initial view of the first tab

Comment: Method create would do fine for the first tab